# "show more" function in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sorry for my english 
I'm new in angular and JS

I created this plank - `http://plnkr.co/edit/stDVowlSq7e5wUw5YwHN?p=preview`
how I can add the "show more" function such like this `http://jsfiddle.net/HPu9n/44/` in my plank example, in:

```
angular.module('module3', [])
.controller('testCtrl3', function($scope){
$scope.query = {}
$scope.queryBy = '$'
$scope.items = [
  {
    "name" : "Ananchenko Juriy",
    "company" : "GOOGLE. Ltd",
    "designation" : "Creativ Director"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Ananchenko",
    "company" : "GOOGLE"
  },
  {
    "name" : "Korman Juriy",
    "company" : "GOOGLE. Ltd",
    "designation" : "stager na ispitatelnom sroke"
  }
];
$scope.orderProp="name";
```

});

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I made the first plank - (http://plnkr.co/edit/stDVowlSq7e5wUw5YwHN?p=preview) - relying on other people's examples and found an example "show more" function but I was not able to combine them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, not sure if I get your question right ...

Everything is allready there in the fiddle, you just need to copy it to your plunker.

There would be:
The directive with the filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in items | filter:query | limitTo: itemsLimit()">
```

and the coressponding code in you controller

```
var pagesShown = 1;
var pageSize = 2;
$scope.itemsLimit = function() {
    return pageSize * pagesShown;
};
$scope.hasMoreItemsToShow = function() {
    return pagesShown < ($scope.items.length / pageSize);
};
$scope.showMoreItems = function() {
    pagesShown = pagesShown + 1;         
};
```

pageSize is set to 2 for demonstration purpose.

[Forked your plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3ea57MaVis9S1N4gMOw6?p=preview)

Comment: oh! thank you very much, I forgot to add - | limitTo: itemsLimit() - in ng-repeat

Comment: No, in your plunker you also forgot the functions in your controller. Happens to me all the times:-)

Comment: thank you, i understand that-), but I preferred to provide two clean and 100% working examples to make their easier and clearer